# Format Data labels in Chart depending on own value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am making a report in Reporting Services. In the charts, I want to show data labels with values in my charts. However, if the numbers become to big, I want to shorten then like this:

> 5300 -> 5.3k
>
> 5,300,000 -> 5.3M

In Textboxes and Tables I can do this using the following formula as a
format:

```
=Switch(    
    ReportItems!Textbox15.Value < 1000, "€0.#",
    ReportItems!Textbox15.Value < 1000000, "€#,.#K",
    true, "€#,,.0M")
```

I found out that you can also change the Textbox name in the formula to Me:

```
=Switch(
   Me.Value < 1000, "€0.#",
   Me.Value < 1000000, "€#,.#K",
   true,"€#,,.0M")
```

Is there any way to accomplish the same for data labels in charts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the field that holds the value.

```
=Switch(    
    Fields!Amount.Value < 1000, "€0.#",
    Fields!Amount.Value < 1000000, "€#,.#K",
    true, "€#,,.0M"
)
```

If your value is calculated using a specific expression you have to use that expression in the `FORMAT` property.

```
=Switch(    
    AVG(Fields!Amount.Value) < 1000, "€0.#",
    AVG(Fields!Amount.Value) < 1000000, "€#,.#K",
    true, "€#,,.0M"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.